# appending element to vector - is it real time operation?

Tags: algorithm, real-time

Having traditional vector like `std::vector` with some n elements and appending element using `push_back` method, can we say, that we are doing real-time operation?

From one point of view, with knowledge, that every time elements in the vector doubles, the memory is reallocated once again we can predict with how many elements  how long it will take for the operation to perform, so we can say when it might have complexity of O(n) and when O(1). On the other hand, real-time algorithms should be very stable, so having two complexities depending on some internal conditions might be unacceptable.

So how is it in the end?

Comment: Yes I know, still question is if we can call it real-time operation, and therefore can we use vectors in critical operations.

Comment: Not all `std::vector` implementations double the length of the allocation when they must grow.  For example, Visual C++ grows by 1.5 times.  As long as the factor is greater than 1, you get amortized constant time.  When the factor gets to 2 or higher, then you can have pathological consumption of the address space (all of the space freed in the previous growth operations can never form a space large enough for another doubling).  This rarely matters in general purpose systems, but, since you're asking about real-time, you might have a more constrained address space to consider.

Comment: if you must use dynamic size grow-able arrays then preallocate when you got the time ... for example you got some RT critical ISR  then call some maintenance routine after it is executed once in a while and preallocate your arrays if needed (not all at once...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No; amortized-constant-time is generally not considered good enough for hard real time. Indeed, for the most part hard real time rules out dynamic memory allocation entirely.